# Nested Form with Nested Resource Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a nested form_for with a nested resource on Rails 4.0.3 However I've come to some problems and have spent quite a lot of time on it.

The problem is when I tried to submit the forms, the values are not save in my database. It will redirect straight through the `labs#index`

I have defined nested resources and `labs_controller` as follows.

**route.rb**

```
...    
resources :users do
  resources :labs
end
```

**labs_controller.rb** (part of it)

```
class LabsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lab  = Lab.new
  end

  def create
    @lab = Lab.new(lab_params)
    if @lab.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created lab."
      redirect_to user_labs_url
    else
      render :action => 'index'
    end     
  end

  private

    def lab_params
      params.require(:lab).permit(:title, :description, 
        stages_attributes: [:id, :lab_id, :description, 
          tasks_attributes: [:id, :stage_id, :detail, :instruction, :answer ]])
    end
end
```

I have 3 models, `Lab`, `Stage` and `Task` and each one are linked through `has_many` relationship. I also use `CanCan` to handle the authorization.

**lab.rb**

```
class Lab < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stages
  resourcify

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stages
end
```

**stage.rb**

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lab
  has_many :tasks
  resourcify

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stage
  resourcify

end
```

Here's my form partials.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@user, @lab] do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.label :description%>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :stages do |builder| %>
    <%= render "labs/partials/stage_fields", f: builder %>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**_stage_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</fieldset>

<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
  <%= render "labs/partials/task_fields", f:builder %>
<% end %>
```

**_task_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :detail %>
  <%= f.text_area :detail %>
  <%= f.label :instruction %>
  <%= f.text_area :instruction %>
  <%= f.label :answer %>
  <%= f.text_field :answer %>
</fieldset>
```

I've gone through several questions and none of it is working for me. Eg.

- [form_for with nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources)
- [nested form nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393464/form-for-nested-resource)

I also try to follow Ryan Bates on Nested Model Form and still no luck. Hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try accessing builder in your partials and not f maybe? or try doing it without the partials and just triple nested in one form, maybe the partials are causing the problem

Comment: @flylib Hi, I've manage to fix the partial not rendering. It's just some wrong partial path that I've overlooked. But I still can't figure out why it's not saving to the database.

Comment: Can you post your `log information` when submitting the `form`?

Comment: @Pavan I've created a pastebin for the log. http://pastebin.com/rAB4JyMj. I've noticed that it says `Unpermitted parameters: stage`. Did I declare it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error logs it is probably a problem with your `lab_params` function.  When you look at the Parameters that are passed in you want to match those with your permit options.  Then check out the [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) docs for guidance on how to handle nested params.

```
   def lab_params
      params.require(:lab).permit(:title, :description,
        :stage => [:id, :lab_id, :description,
          :tasks => [:id, :stage_id, :detail, :instruction, :answer ]
        ]
      )
    end
```

I think this should get you beyond that error.

Comment: This actually works. Thanks. Though if I may ask, What is the differences between `:stage` & `:stages`?